# speeding up vivado 2017.2

Tags: fpga, vhdl, speed, vivado

Hi I am using vivado 2017.2 and it takes infinite amount of time for sythesis and even I suspect that vivado is stuck because I get nowhere. How can I speed the process up? What settings can I change for this purpose?

I am using Basys3 FPGA board and coding in VHDL if this information helps. I did everything I could think of. I got rid of for loops and put cascaded if statements which gave me functionality of clocked for loops in an hope that it could speed up the process. I browsed internet and could not find anything useful. Functionality of this code is high but it is required to be so. My computer is not old and works finely in terms of speed.

And here is the some part of the code I am writing. It is simply a code for some image processing(changing contrast/brigtness in a small square I move on the picture on the screen)

```
  type pixels is array (0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 1, 0 to 
  PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 
  1) of std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
  type RamType is array(0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT- 1) of bit_vector(11 downto 
  0);

 signal default_picture : pixels;
 signal processed_picture : pixels := default_picture;

 impure function InitRamFromFile (RamFileName : in string) return RamType is
 FILE RamFile : text is in RamFileName;
 variable RamFileLine : line;
 variable RAM : RamType;
 begin
 for I in RamType'range loop
 readline (RamFile, RamFileLine);
 read (RamFileLine, RAM(I));
 end loop;
 return RAM;
 end function;

 signal RAM : RamType := 
 InitRamFromFile("\\ASUS\Users\AsusPc\Desktop\project_son\pictureData.data");

 begin

 with cursor_mode select length <=
 LENGTH_1 when "00",
 LENGTH_2 when "01",
 LENGTH_3 when "10",
 LENGTH_4 when "11";

  INITIALIZING_DEFAULT_PICTURE: process(default_clk) is
  variable ram_counter : integer range 0 to 62499 := 0;
  begin
  if rising_edge(default_clk) then
  for i in 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 1 loop
  for j in 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 1 loop
  default_picture(i,j) <= (to_stdlogicvector(RAM(ram_counter)));
  ram_counter := ram_counter + 1;
  end loop;
  end loop;
  end if;
  end process ;


  CLOCK_DIVIDER: process (default_clk, rst) begin
    if (rst = '1') then
    temporal <= '0';
    counter <= 0;             
   elsif rising_edge(default_clk) then
    if (counter = 1) then
        temporal <= NOT(temporal);
        counter <= 0;
    else
        counter <= counter + 1;
   end if;
   end if;
   end process;

   clk <= temporal;

   CNT_H : process (clk, rst) is
   begin  -- process CNT_H
   if rst = '1' then
   COUNTER_H <= 0;
   NEW_LINE  <= '0';
   elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
   if (COUNTER_H = TOTAL_H-1) then
   COUNTER_H <= 0;
   NEW_LINE  <= '1';
   else
   COUNTER_H <= COUNTER_H + 1;
   NEW_LINE  <= '0';        
   end if;
   end if;
   end process CNT_H;

   CNT_V : process (clk, rst) is
   begin  -- process CNT_V
   if rst = '1' then
   COUNTER_V <= 0;
   elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
   if (NEW_LINE = '1') then
   if (COUNTER_V = TOTAL_V-1) then
   COUNTER_V <= 0;          
   else
   COUNTER_V <= COUNTER_V + 1;
   end if;
   end if;
   end if;
   end process CNT_V;

   SYNC_H : process (clk, rst) is
   begin  -- process SYNC_H
   if rst = '1' then
   hs_out <= '0';
   elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
   if (COUNTER_H < H_SYNC_TIME) then
   hs_out <= '0';
   else
   hs_out <= '1';
   end if;
   end if;
   end process SYNC_H;

   SYNC_V : process (clk, rst) is
   begin  -- process SYNC_V
   if rst = '1' then
   vs_out <= '0';
   elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
   if (COUNTER_V < V_SYNC_TIME) then
   vs_out <= '0';
   else
   vs_out <= '1';
   end if;
   end if;
   end process SYNC_V;

   AREA_H : process (clk, rst) is
   begin  -- process AREA_H
   if rst = '1' then
   h_visible <= '0';
   elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
   if (COUNTER_H > H_SYNC_TIME + H_BACK_PORCH - 1) and (COUNTER_H < TOTAL_H - 
   H_FRONT_PORCH) then
   h_visible <= '1';
   if ((COUNTER_H - (H_SYNC_TIME + H_BACK_PORCH)) <641) then
   pos_x <= COUNTER_H - (H_SYNC_TIME + H_BACK_PORCH);
   end if;
   else
   h_visible <= '0';
   end if;
   end if;
   end process AREA_H;

   AREA_V : process (clk, rst) is
   begin  -- process AREA_V
   if rst = '1' then
   v_visible <= '0';
   elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
   if (COUNTER_V > V_SYNC_TIME + V_BACK_PORCH - 1) and (COUNTER_V < TOTAL_V - 
   V_FRONT_PORCH) then
   v_visible <= '1';
   if ((COUNTER_V - (V_SYNC_TIME + V_BACK_PORCH)) < 481) then
   pos_y     <= COUNTER_V - (V_SYNC_TIME + V_BACK_PORCH);
   end if;
   else
    v_visible <= '0';
    end if;
    end if;
    end process AREA_V;

    visible <= h_visible and v_visible;

    GOING_LEFT: process (go_left) is
    begin
    if go_left = '1' and (cursor_pos_x - length - 1 > 0) then
    cursor_pos_x <= cursor_pos_x - length  - 1;
    end if;
    if go_left = '1' and (cursor_pos_x - length  - 1 < 0) then
    cursor_pos_x <= 0;
    end if;            
    end process GOING_LEFT;

    GOING_RIGHT: process ( go_right) is
    begin
    if go_right = '1' and (cursor_pos_x + length  - 1 < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT)  
    then      
    cursor_pos_x <= cursor_pos_x + length  - 1;
    end if;
    if go_right = '1' and ( cursor_pos_x + length  - 1 > PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT 
    - 1) 
    then
    cursor_pos_x <= 249;
    end if;
    end process GOING_RIGHT;

    GOING_UP: process (go_up) is
    begin
    if go_up = '1' and (cursor_pos_y - length  -1 > 0)  then      
    cursor_pos_y <= cursor_pos_y - length  - 1;
    end if;
    if go_up = '1' and ( cursor_pos_y - length  - 1 < 0) then
    cursor_pos_y <= 0;
    end if;
    end process GOING_UP;

    GOING_DOWN: process (go_down) is
    begin
    if go_down = '1' and (cursor_pos_y + length - 1 < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT)  
    then      
    cursor_pos_y <= cursor_pos_y + length  - 1;
    end if;
    if go_down = '1' and (cursor_pos_y + length  -1 > PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 
    1) then
    cursor_pos_y <= 248 - length ;
    end if;
    end process GOING_DOWN;

    SHOW : process (clk, rst) is
    begin     
    if rst = '1' then

    processed_picture <= default_picture;
    cursor_pos_x <= 0;
    cursor_pos_y <= 0;

    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then

    if (visible = '1') and ( pos_x < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) and (pos_y 
    <PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) and (pos_x > -1) and (pos_y > -1) then

    if((pos_y = cursor_pos_y) and ((pos_x > cursor_pos_x -1) or (pos_x < 
    cursor_pos_x + length ))) or ((pos_y = cursor_pos_y + length -1) and 
    ((pos_x > cursor_pos_x -1) or (pos_x < cursor_pos_x + length))) then
            vgaData <= "000000000000";
            data_r <= vgaData(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT);
            data_g <= vgaData(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT);
            data_b <= vgaData(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);       

    elsif ((pos_x = cursor_pos_x) and ((pos_y > cursor_pos_y - 1) or (pos_y < 
    cursor_pos_y + length))) or ((pos_x = cursor_pos_x + length -1) and 
    ((pos_y > 
    cursor_pos_y - 1) or (pos_y < cursor_pos_y + length))) then
            vgaData <= "000000000000";
            data_r <= vgaData(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT);
            data_g <= vgaData(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT);
            data_b <= vgaData(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);
    else       
            vgaData <= processed_picture(pos_x,pos_y);
            data_r <= vgaData(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT);
            data_g <= vgaData(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT);
            data_b <= vgaData(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);
    end if;
    if ((pos_x > PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 1) and (pos_y > -1)) or ((pos_y > 
    PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 1) and ((pos_x > -1) or (pos_x < 
    PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT))) then
            vgaData <= "000000001111"; -- mavi
            data_r <= vgaData(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT);
            data_g <= vgaData(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT);
            data_b <= vgaData(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0);

   end if;
   end if;
   end if;

   end process SHOW;

   ADJUSTING_i_and_j: process(enable) is
   begin
   if(enable = '0') then
   i <= 0;
   j <= 0;
   end if;
   end process;

   ADJUSTING_cpx_and_cpy: process(length) is
   begin
   cursor_pos_x <= 0;
   cursor_pos_y <= 0;
   end process;


   BRIGHTNESS: process(enable, default_clk) is

   begin

   if enable = '1' then
   if operation = "00" then
   if rising_edge(default_clk) then

   if mode = '0' then --mode     

   if( i < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then --i
   if( j < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then --j

   if ( i > cursor_pos_x - 1) and (i < cursor_pos_x + length) and ( j > 
   cursor_pos_y - 1) and (j < cursor_pos_y + length) then -- condition

   if processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) < 14 then
   processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) <= 
   processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) + 2;
   end if;

   if processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) < 14 then
   processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) <= 
   processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) + 2;
   end if;

   if processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) < 14 then
   processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) <= processed_picture(i,j) 
   (COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) + 2;
   end if;

   end if; --condition

   j <= j + 1;

   if( j = PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then
   j <= 0;
   i <= i + 1;
   end if;

   end if; --j
   end if; --i

   end if; --mode  

   if mode = '1' then --mode

   if( i < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then --i
   if( j < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then --j

   if ( i > cursor_pos_x - 1) and (i < cursor_pos_x + length) and ( j > 
   cursor_pos_y - 1) and (j < cursor_pos_y + length) then --condition

   if processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) > 1 then
   processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) <= 
   processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) - 2;
   end if;

   if processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) > 1 then
   processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) <= 
   processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) - 2;
   end if;

   if processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) > 1 then
   processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) <= processed_picture(i,j) 
   (COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) - 2;
   end if;

   end if; --condition

   j <= j + 1;

   if( j = PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then
   j <= 0;
   i <= i + 1;
   end if;

   end if; --j

   end if; --i      

   end if; --mode

   end if; --enable
   end if; --operation
   end if; --clock

   end process BRIGHTNESS;

  CONTRAST: process(enable, default_clk) is
  begin
  if enable = '1' then
  if operation = "01" then
  if rising_edge(default_clk) then

  if mode = '0' then

  if( i < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then --i
  if( j < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then --j

  if ( i > cursor_pos_x - 1) and (i < cursor_pos_x + length) and ( j > 
  cursor_pos_y - 1) and (j < cursor_pos_y + length) then -- condition

  if  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) < 8 and 
  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) > 1 then
  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) <= 
  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) - 2;
  end if;

  if processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) > 7 and 
  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) < 14 then
  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) <= 
  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) +2 ;
  end if;

  if  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) < 8 and 
  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) > 1 then
  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) <= 
  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) - 2;
  end if;

  if processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) > 7 and 
  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) < 14 then
  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) <= 
  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) +2 ;
  end if;

  if  processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) < 8 and 
  processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) > 1 then
  processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) <= processed_picture(i,j) 
  (COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) - 2;
  end if;

  if processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) > 7 and 
  processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) < 14 then
  processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) <= processed_picture(i,j) 
  (COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) +2 ;
  end if;

  end if; --condition

  j <= j + 1;

  if( j = PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then
  j <= 0;
  i <= i + 1;
  end if;

  end if; --j
  end if; --i

  end if; --mode

  if mode = '1' then

  if( i < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then --i
  if( j < PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then --j

  if ( i > cursor_pos_x - 1) and (i < cursor_pos_x + length) and ( j > 
  cursor_pos_y - 1) and (j < cursor_pos_y + length) then --condition

  if  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) < 8 and 
  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) > 2 then
  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) <= 
  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) - 3;
  end if;

  if processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) > 7 and 
  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) < 13 then
  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) <= 
  processed_picture(i,j)(3*COLOR_BIT-1 downto 2*COLOR_BIT) +3 ;
  end if;

  if  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) < 8 and 
  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) > 2 then
  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) <= 
  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) - 3;
  end if;

  if processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) > 7 and 
  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) < 13 then
  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) <= 
  processed_picture(i,j)(2*COLOR_BIT-1 downto COLOR_BIT) +3 ;
  end if;

  if  processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) < 8 and 
  processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) > 2 then
  processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) <= processed_picture(i,j) 
  (COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) - 3;
  end if;

  if processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) > 7 and 
  processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) < 13 then
  processed_picture(i,j)(COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) <= processed_picture(i,j) 
 (COLOR_BIT-1 downto 0) + 3 ;
  end if;

  end if; --condition

  j <= j + 1;

  if( j = PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT) then
  j <= 0;
  i <= i + 1;
  end if;

  end if; --j
  end if; --i

  end if; --mode

  end if; --clock
  end if; --operation
  end if; --enable

  end process CONTRAST;



  end VGA;
```

Comment: Have you learned nothing at all from your previous questions? *For loops generate parallel hardware.* You must avoid them unless you really want that. Take advantage of the fact that video signals are generally received and transmitted serially (one pixel at a time), and do your image processing (including initialization) the same way.

Comment: I am learning in a hard way :(

Comment: oh my that's a millions of nested ifs and for loops. The very first thing you can read in any xilinx doc is "avoid nested ifs" wherever possible. Ity will generate poorest performing hardware and hence synthesiser cant optimise logic properly. Hence it will take hours for routing. Code simple, then synthesiser also gives you back simple things. This is not c/c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're vastly underestimating the complexity of the code. The important value of PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT is missing, but from the range of ram_counter (0..62499) it seems like you are instantiating about 47,000,000,000 flipflops in this code.

I hope that this is not the case and the range of ram_counter is simply wrong. You have to make sure that all your data can fit into a RAM block, which is not the case at the moment.

```
  for i in 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 1 loop
  for j in 0 to PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT - 1 loop
  default_picture(i,j) <= (to_stdlogicvector(RAM(ram_counter)));
  ram_counter := ram_counter + 1;
  end loop;
  end loop;
```

What you are doing here is essentially copying a huge amount of data within one clock cycle - this means that all Bits have to be available at the same time, which hinders packing them in a RAM, but requires individual FF.

I recommend to generate a RAM block from the core generator and use this instead of declaring huge arrays - this way you are forced to adhere to the internal structure of RAM blocks and eventually can reach a state with a resource consumption low enough to fit into the FPGA.

Comment: It's really just 1,500,000 FFs (62500*12*2 -- `default_picture` + `processed_picture`), but still...

Comment: @DaveTweed 'pixels' is a two-dimensional array of std_logic_vectors with both dimensions identical to 'RAM'. That's 62500**2.

Comment: I don't think so. As you say, `PICTURE_WIDTH_HEIGHT` isn't specified, but the way it's used in the double loop with `ram_counter`, which ranges from 0 to 62499, we have to assume that is is equal to 250. My impression is that RamType holds just one line (or one column) of pixels.